# How does the Heightened Spell metamagic work on the Immolation spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, sorcerer, saving-throw, metamagic

I've been looking for an answer on how the sorcerer's Heightened Spell Metamagic option would affect the *immolation* spell. Would it apply to all the Dex saves of the spell? Or would it only apply to the initial Dex save?

Sorry if this is obvious; Metamagic is quite different from other forms of casting a spell.

Comment: Hi PyroManiac, welcome to RPG.SE. Remember to check out the [tour] and [help] some time for further information about asking and answering questions.

Comment: I've noticed you haven't marked any of your questions with an accepted answer. This can be done by clicking on the check mark under the voting buttons for the answer that best solves your problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The description of the Heightened Spell [Metamagic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#Metamagic-372) option says (emphasis mine):

> When you cast a spell that forces a creature to make a saving throw to resist its effects, you can spend 3 sorcery points to give one target of the spell disadvantage **on its first saving throw made against the spell.**

Heightened Spell only ever changes the first saving throw made against a spell. And it only ever applies to *one* creature, too.